# Find longest prefix in Percona

Tags: mysql, sql, percona

**Longest prefix matched**

I'm looking for the longest prefix that matches a phone number in my Percona DB.

- The prefix could either be stored as BIGINT or VARCHAR.
- You may have a separate column for temp data if you like (eg. prefix length).
- The table is read heavy (about thousands/s) and is only written to a few times/day.
- The data size is in the order of 30-70M records.

**What I have so far**

```
CREATE TABLE Prefixes (
  `Prefix` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Prefix`));

SELECT Prefix
FROM Prefixes
WHERE Prefix IN (1234567, 123456, 12345, 1234, 123, 12, 1)
ORDER BY LENGTH(Prefix) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This works but I would like it to perform faster and allow me to use prepared statements.

**What I'm thinking**

- The DB probably have a B-tree lookup thing going on anyway, If I could use that directly it would speed up the lookup.
- The SQL query looks really ugly, especially if you use placeholders since you'll need one prepared statement for every number of prefix lengths.